# How to pass a PowerShell script using user_data (AWS and Terraform)?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to pass the PowerShell script as the file `IIS.txt` which is present in the `CWD`.

I don't see the script running on the server. I am not sure if I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
resource "aws_instance" "db1" {
  ami           = "ami-1234567890"  
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  subnet_id     = "${aws_subnet.db.0.id}"
  key_name      = "ireland"
  user_data     = "${file("IIS.txt")}"

  tags = {
    Name = "sql node 1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the directory structure in either `ls -la` or `tree` command outputs? If you're on windows, `dir /s` would do too. The `IIS.txt` file should be in the same directory where you run `terraform` commands.

Comment: C:\Users\%\Desktop\AWS\AWS\Running PS script through Terraform

10/03  03:47 PM    <DIR>          .
10/03  03:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/02  12:53 PM    <DIR>          .terraform
10/03 02:05 PM               133 IIS.txt
10/03  03:27 PM             1,254 Instances.tf
06/21  06:44 AM               116 Provider.tf
10/03  03:47 PM               157 terraform.tfstate
10/03  03:46 PM            12,052 terraform.tfstate.backup
10/02  10:50 AM               420 terraform.tfvars
10/02  12:58 PM               710 vars.tf
10/03  03:03 PM             1,318 vpc-subnets.tf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a template_file data and local_file resource for this.

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("iis.txt")}"
}

resource "local_file" "user_data" {
  content  = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
  filename = "user_data-${sha1(data.template_file.user_data.rendered)}.ps"
}
```

Then update your `user_data` property content of the local_file resource.

```
resource "aws_instance" "db1"
{
  ami           = "ami-1234567890"  
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  subnet_id     = "${aws_subnet.db.0.id}"
  key_name      = "ireland"
  user_data     = "${local_file.user_data.content}"
  tags =
  {
    Name = "sql node 1"
  }
}
```

This also allows you to get a little fancier and do a template script, and pull TF variables, etc into the template and render it just in time before you deploy.

Comment: Note if this doesn't work you may need to share some of the contents of your script file "iis.txt". There are requirements for how user_data is formatted for it to actually be executed as a script.

Comment: IIS.txt

    <<-EOF
    <powershell>
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludemanagementTools
    </powershell>
    EOF

@Dude0001 I will test your solution

Comment: Is the heredoc/EOF stuff literal characters in the .txt? If so I think you need to take them out. The file should start with <poweshell> and end with <\powershell> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html